# Why is WP-Query spelled like it is?

Tags: wp-query

I'm new to PHP and WordPress, and I'm curious:

Why is WP-Query capitalized like it is?

Is this a PHP naming convention, based on the type of query?  Or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WP_Query` is a [PHP Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), class names are capitalized, with words separated by underscores, as per the [Naming Conventions in WordPress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Naming_Conventions).